# apache2: Is it possible to run mod_proxy on a differnt port?

Tags: port, mod-proxy, apache-2.2

I've a running apache2 listening on port 80 serving some websites.

mod_proxy is configured for forward-proxying.

I'd like to have mod_proxy only listening to a separate port as 80

```
<Proxy *:55000>
```

Here I tried Port 55000. But this doesn't work :(

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Casper

Answer (score 1):

```
Set ProxyRequests off globally, then 

Listen 0.0.0.0:55000
<virtualhost *:55000>
ProxyRequests on
</virtualhost>
```

Comment: Then the normale websites are no longer served via port 80 :-\

Comment: Why would normal content care if you set ProxyRequests off and added a listen and a vhost?   The site ate my 

<virtualhost *:55000>

Comment: Your post above was not displayed correct. The "virtual host" line is not displayed in my browser (IE and FF tried). Only if I "edit" your post, all is shown.. Strange.

Comment: sorry about that, wrapping it in the code tags fixed it